# SQL Server Adding Order with CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, common-table-expression

I want to achieve something easy in an while loop but it's too slow to run so I'm sure I can do this with an CTE table but I don't know how..

I have two table with a join one to many and i'm trying to put an order in my detail here's my data:

[image]

for each IDRV you have many IDRVOBJET. I want to put an order number 1 to n for each IDRVOBJET in IDRV. I don't know if i'm clear but here's what I should have as result:

[image]

Thanks for taking the time to help me!

EDIT

Here's the formated text:

```
IDRV  IDRVOBJET ORDER
12700   76357   1
12700   76358   2
12701   76363   1
12701   76364   2
12701   76365   3
12702   76359   1
12702   76360   2
12703   76120   1
12703   76121   2
12703   76122   3
12705   19375   1
12705   19376   2
12706   19410   1
12707   19408   1
12707   19409   2
12709   22473   1
12709   22474   2
12711   40352   1
12711   40353   1
```

Comment: @jarlh I understand it was just to be more clear. I just put the formated text in my Edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a window function.

```
SELECT
   IDRV,
   IDRVOBJECT,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDRV ORDER BY IDRVOBJECT) as ORDRE
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: It works!! ...OMG shame on me -_- about 1 hours on this. If you could explain a little bit more how it works i'll help me next time :)
Thank you

Comment: ROW_NUMBER you can read about [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) but the key is the partition and order by. Order by is REQUIRED in Window Functions like ROW_NUMBER(), and PARTITION BY is optional. PARTITION essentially groups, or partitions the result sets so without it, your entire result set would be ordered without consideration as to what the IDRV was. Take it out and see the difference :). Also try ASC and DESC after ORDER BY.

Comment: thanks a lot men! I did try row_number but i didn't know the partition part of it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number and partition by

```
 select *, Ordr = Row_Number() over (partition by IDRV order by IDRVOBJET) from your table
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IDRV,IDRVOBJECT,Row_Number()Over(Partition by IDRV Order by IDRVOBJECT) AS ORDRE
FROM <yourtable>
```